# want to get pagespeed in my view page on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have implemented the google page speed on rails 4 with the help of pagespeed gem but I am getting my result on console. I want this result on my view page.

Controller code:-

```
 @request = PageSpeed::Request::new("www.google.com", 'api key', 'desktop')
puts @request.pagespeed
```

Answer (score 1):

The instance variable @request defined in your controller will be available in your views as

```
<%= @request %>
```

for pagespeed

```
<%= @request.pagespeed %>
```

Comment: first of all, as I know that we can't write '=' both side means to represent the view we always write this tag "<%= request %>". Anway I tried by both but did not get the result on view. On first "<%= @request %>" I got this on view "#<PageSpeed::Request:0x007f8a2b7c6f48>" and on second one am getting blank page. Please let me know if you know any solution for it.

Comment: Edited and corrected the '=' . <PageSpeed::Request:0x007f8a2b7c6f48> is the @request object you see. Print any of its attribute like you normally would. Blank means it has nil value.